# Sorting in ascending order using pointers

Tags: c, sorting, pointers

I am writing a program to sort 3 integers in ascending order using pointers and I have coded the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void compare_and_swap(int *const a, int *const b) {
    int t;

    if (*a > *b) {
        t = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = t;
     }

void  sort (int * const pint1, int * const pint2, int *const pint3)
    {
       if (*pint1 > *pint2){compare_and_swap(pint1, pint2);}
       if (*pint2 > *pint3){compare_and_swap(pint2, pint3);}
       if (*pint1 > *pint3){compare_and_swap(pint1, pint3);}
     }

int main (void)
    {
         void  sort (int * const pint1, int *  const pint2, int * pint3);
         int   i1 = -5, i2 = 66, i3 =77, *p1 = &i1, *p2 = &i2, *p3 = &i3;
         int x;
         printf ("i1 = %i, i2 = %i, i3=%i \n", i1, i2,i3);

         sort (p1, p2,p3);
         printf ("i1 = %i, i2 = %i, i3= %i \n", x);

         return 0;
    }
```

The output I am getting is some garbage values:

```
i1 = -5, i2 = 66, i3=77 
i1 = 0, i2 = 1427618548, i3= -5
```

Comment: Any reason to use constant qualifier ?

Comment: Also you print an uninitalized variable `x` .What would you expect then ?

Comment: I don't understand what is your question. You don't even have the correct argument in your second printf...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing one argument to `printf()` where it expects three. Enable compilation warnings so the compiler can tell you about this.

```
printf ("i1 = %i, i2 = %i, i3= %i \n", x);
```

Changing it to

```
printf ("i1 = %i, i2 = %i, i3= %i \n",i1,i2,i3);
```

should work.

Also read something about one of the most famous and basic sorting algorithm [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort][1] , because your does not give correct results for given numbers in descending order